# If statement with text box not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, if-statement

I have five text boxes that are  subclassed views that cycle values from an array when touched. They are all blank to start off with.

If the box receives a value of `@"\u2714"`I want to fill the others automatically with N/A.

What ive tried so far dosent change the the text box values when `@"\u2714"` is received. Not sure what im doing wrong here?

here is  my nsarray:    `//self.valuesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\u2714", @"X", @"LIM", @"N/A", nil];`

If I set the string to any of the values from the array,  the text boxes do not populate with N/A.  If I set the `isEqualToString:sting` to `@""` I can get my text box values to all default to N/A, but not based on any inputs from when cycling through the array

```
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTncs"]).value;
    if ([self.tncsTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@"X"]){
    self.tncTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTns"]).value;
    if ([self.tnsTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@""]){
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tncTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }
    self.tncTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTnc"]).value;
    if ([self.tncTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@""]){
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }

    self.itTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeIt"]).value;
    if ([self.itTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@""]){
    self.tncTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }

    self.ttTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTt"]).value;
    if ([self.ttTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@""]){
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }




    self.tncsTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTncs"]).value;
    if ([self.tncsTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
    self.tncTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTns"]).value;
    if ([self.tnsTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tncTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }
    self.tncTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTnc"]).value;
    if ([self.tncTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }

    self.itTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeIt"]).value;
    if ([self.itTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
    self.tncTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }

    self.ttTapView.textValue = ([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTt"]).value;
    if ([self.ttTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
    self.ttTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tnsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.itTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    self.tncsTapView.textValue = @"N/A";
    }
```

Comment: try `self.tncsTapView.text` instead of `self.tncsTapView.textValue`

Comment: Have you set breakpoint to step through your code and see if any of the if statements are being entered?

Comment: Maybe you could define what about it is not working.

Comment: @ Pratyush Terli, .text tried that but get error is object not found on my subclass `ICTapView`

Comment: post your attributWithName: code as well

Comment: Pratyusha `([self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTncs"]).value = [ICUtils nonNilString:self.tncsTapView.textField.text];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backslash in an NSString is represented by two consecutive backslashes.  In all your if statements, try the following:

```
if ([self.tncsTapView.textValue isEqualToString:@"\\u2714"])
```

Comment: What are the tapViews?  If these are UILabels or UITextFields, you also have to change all the statements to `self.tncsTapView.text` or such, as Sharanya and Pratyusha said.

Comment: tap views are a view subclassed

Comment: Then, if `textValue` is a subclass property, and all you care about is its value, your code is correct.  If you are trying to display the new value (`@"N\A"`) in a text field, you may need to change all the statements to `self.tncsTapView.textField.text` or its equivalent. From your question, it's not clear what you mean by "your text box values".

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
self.tncsTapView.text = [self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTncs"];

    if ([self.tncsTapView.text hasPrefix:@"\u2714"])
    {
    }
```

Comment: @JSA986 are you using text box?

Answer (score 0):

I guess its that you have to remove Value everywhere... When you assign , you assign it as text and while checking also u check it as text only..

```
self.tncsTapView.text = [self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTncs"];
if ([self.tncsTapView.text isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
self.tncTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.tnsTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.itTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.ttTapView.text = @"N/A";
}
self.tnsTapView.text = [self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTns"];
if ([self.tnsTapView.text isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
self.tncsTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.tncTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.itTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.ttTapView.text = @"N/A";
}
self.tncTapView.text = [self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTnc"];
if ([self.tncTapView.text isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
self.tncsTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.tnsTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.itTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.ttTapView.text = @"N/A";
}

self.itTapView.text = [self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeIt"];
if ([self.itTapView.text isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
self.tncTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.tnsTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.tncsTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.ttTapView.text = @"N/A";
}

self.ttTapView.text = [self attributeWithName:@"systemTypeTt"];
if ([self.ttTapView.text isEqualToString:@"\u2714"]){
self.ttTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.tnsTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.itTapView.text = @"N/A";
self.tncsTapView.text = @"N/A";
}
```